# Tuple trouble when trying to count elements in a list?

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, beautifulsoup, tuples

I am trying to count the number of contractions used by politicians in certain speeches. I have lots of speeches, but here are some of the URLs as a sample:

```
every_link_test = ['http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4427',
 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4424',
 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4453',
 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-4612',
 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/obama/speeches/speech-5502']
```

I have a pretty rough counter right now - it only counts the total number of contractions used in all of those links. For example, the following code returns `79,101,101,182,224` for the five links above. However, I want to link up `filename`, a variable I create below, so I would have something like `(speech_1, 79),(speech_2, 22),(speech_3,0),(speech_4,81),(speech_5,42)`. That way, I can track the number of contractions used in each individual speech. I'm getting the following error with my code: `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'split'`

Here's my code:

```
import urllib2,sys,os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup,NavigableString
from string import punctuation as p
from multiprocessing import Pool
import re, nltk
import requests
reload(sys)

url = 'http://www.millercenter.org/president/speeches'
url2 = 'http://www.millercenter.org'

conn = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = conn.read()

miller_center_soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
links = miller_center_soup.find_all('a')

linklist = [tag.get('href') for tag in links if tag.get('href') is not None]

# remove all items in list that don't contain 'speeches'
linkslist = [_ for _ in linklist if re.search('speeches',_)]
del linkslist[0:2]

# concatenate 'http://www.millercenter.org' with each speech's URL ending
every_link_dups = [url2 + end_link for end_link in linkslist]

# remove duplicates
seen = set()
every_link = [] # no duplicates array
for l in every_link_dups:
    if l not in seen:
        every_link.append(l)
        seen.add(l)

def processURL_short_2(l):
    open_url = urllib2.urlopen(l).read()
    item_soup = BeautifulSoup(open_url)
    item_div = item_soup.find('div',{'id':'transcript'},{'class':'displaytext'})
    item_str = item_div.text.lower()

    splitlink = l.split("/")
    president = splitlink[4]
    speech_num = splitlink[-1]
    filename = "{0}_{1}".format(president, speech_num)
    return item_str, filename

every_link_test = every_link[0:5]
print every_link_test
count = 0
for l in every_link_test:
    content_1 = processURL_short_2(l)
    for word in content_1.split():
        word = word.strip(p)
        if word in contractions:
            count = count + 1        
    print count, filename
```

Comment: Well, python doesn't lie. `split` is for `strings`. [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split)

Comment: Either your indentation is off or else you have some variable naming issues with`l`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `print count, filename`, you should save these data to a data structure, like a dictionary. Since `processURL_short_2` has been modified to return a tuple, you'll need to unpack it.

```
data = {} # initialize a dictionary
for l in every_link_test:
    content_1, filename = processURL_short_2(l) # unpack the content and filename
    for word in content_1.split():
        word = word.strip(p)
        if word in contractions:
            count = count + 1        
    data[filename] = count # add this to the dictionary as filename:count
```

This would give you a dictionary like `{'obama_4424':79, 'obama_4453':101,...}`, allowing you to easily store and access your parsed data.

Comment: Just a note, the code has a syntax error around `content_1.split()`. content_1 is a tuple. I mentioned in my answer how to handle it.

Comment: @idjaw - Thanks. I assume you mean an `AttributeError` and not `SyntaxError`, right? Anyway, fixed. The OP said that they had gotten results, so I thought they had working code to which they wanted to add a feature, rather than an unsuccessful attempt at adding that feature.

Comment: Yes, `AttributeError`. Sorry...doing too many things at once :P

Comment: That's what I intend to do: save it to a data structure. I want to have it just like your dictionary looks. Thanks for your help - I got it.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message explains, you cannot use split the way you are using it. split is for strings.

So you will need to change this:

```
for word in content_1.split():
```

to this:

```
for word in content_1[0]:
```

I chose `[0]` by running your code, I think that gives you the chunk of the text you are looking to search through.

@TigerhawkT3 has a good suggestion you should follow in their answer too:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981533/1832539

Comment: contractions does exist in a list like: `{"you're":"you are/you were"}`

Comment: Presumably it should still use `.split()`, just after indexing `content_1`. Or avoid indexing, and unpack the returned tuple into `contents, filename` or somesuch.

Comment: @CarterMasterson could you review your indentation as well? It is way off. I'm no longer getting syntax errors after your data sample you just provided...but the code does not look right in how it is aligned. Can you confirm in your OP how it should be aligned?

Comment: I fixed it above. You are no longer getting syntax errors using what change in code?

Comment: Everything is working on my end. The output does not match what you specified. But no more errors. Are you still having difficulty?

Comment: Mine works! Now, I'm just trying to write the number of contractions and filename to a csv....